# GTM puts blank space nbsp below footer

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

There's a blank space below the footer coming from an `&nbsp;`, all I know is it is coming from GTM. How to remove?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. There were "Custom HTML" GTM tags that had blank lines in them. Removing the blank lines from the "Custom HTML" tags fixed the issue.

**Before:**

```html
<img src="pixelimgurl" />
```

**After:**

```html
<img src="pixelimgurl" />
```

There was still a small bit of extra space remaining after this fix. The following CSS removed that remaining space:

```css
body > img { display: none !important; }
```